# Generated button wont submit data to my google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

i have these function on my google script app to generate some button on a table

> *FYI i have no knowledge of JS, and i just made this with chat GPT*

```
// Function to handle button clicks
function handleButtonClick(rowIndex, colIndex) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
    // Do something after button click, if needed
  }).handleButtonClick(rowIndex, colIndex);
}

// Function to handle date button clicks
function handleDateButtonClick(rowIndex, colIndex) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
    // Do something after date button click, if needed
  }).handleDateButtonClick(rowIndex, colIndex);
}

function submitData(client, tanggalDatang, jenisBarang) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET_ID').getSheetByName('Utama');
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  var matchedRowData = '';
  var totalFound = 0;

  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][3] == client && Utilities.formatDate(values[i][1], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'dd/MM/yyyy') == tanggalDatang && (jenisBarang === '' || values[i][4] == jenisBarang)) {
      totalFound++;
      matchedRowData += '<table class="table table-bordered">';
      for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
        var cellValue = values[i][j];
        var orderId = values[i][0];
        var trId = orderId + '_' + (j + 1);
        if (i === 1) {
          matchedRowData += '<tr id="' + trId + '"><th style="width: 30%; font-weight:bold;">' + values[0][j] + '</th><td>' + cellValue + '</td>';
        } else {
          matchedRowData += '<tr id="' + trId + '"><td style="width: 30%;">' + values[0][j] + '</td><td>' + cellValue + '</td>';
        }
        if (j >= 13 && j <= 19) { 
          matchedRowData += '<td style="width: 15%;"><button onclick="handleButtonClick(' + i + ', ' + (j + 1) + ')">Button</button></td>';
        } else if (j >= 7 && j <= 9) { 
          matchedRowData += '<td style="width: 15%;"><button onclick="handleDateButtonClick(' + i + ', ' + (j + 1) + ')">Add Date</button></td>';
        }
      }
      matchedRowData += '</tr></table><br>';
    }
  }

  matchedRowData = '<h3>Data dari <strong>' + client + '</strong> tanggal <strong>' + tanggalDatang + '</strong> - Total: <strong>' + totalFound + '</strong> item </h3>' + matchedRowData;

  return matchedRowData;
}
```

and this is my script on index html to handle that GS

```
        function handleSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var client = document.getElementById("clientSelect").value;
            var tanggalDatang = document.getElementById("tanggalDatangSelect").value;
            var jenisBarang = document.getElementById("jenisBarangSelect").value;
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (matchedRowData) {
                var matchedRowDiv = document.getElementById("matchedRow");
                matchedRowDiv.innerHTML = matchedRowData;
            }).submitData(client, tanggalDatang, jenisBarang);
        }

        // Function to handle button clicks generated by submitData function
        function handleButtonClick(rowIndex, colIndex) {
            // Implement your logic to handle button clicks here
            alert("Button clicked! Row: " + rowIndex + ", Column: " + colIndex);
        }
```

and [this is the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqgc1.png) when a button clicked

as you see when a button clicked , it could read the spreadsheet cell name that i generate inside 
but it does not submit anything to my sheet.
the log from browser console is

> Uncaught ReferenceError: handleDateButtonClick is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (userCodeAppPanel:1:1)

which part is still wrong?
thank you in advance

> i tried to make a dummy button to post on designated cell, it worked,
> so it wasnt premission issue